# Why does this code affect the cells in column C?

Tags: excel, range, target, vba

This code puts a check mark or an X in column C and changes the font to Marlett:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B5:B25", "D5:D25")) Is Nothing Then

     Cancel = True 'Prevent going into Edit Mode

        Target.Font.Name = "Marlett"

        If Target = vbNullString Then

           Target = "a"

        Else

           Target = vbNullString

        End If

    End If


End Sub
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeRightClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B5:B25", "D5:D25")) Is Nothing Then

     Cancel = True 'Prevent going into Edit Mode

        Target.Font.Name = "Marlett"

        If Target = vbNullString Then

           Target = "r"

        Else

           Target = vbNullString

        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

If you type this in Immediate window (See Screenshot)

```
?Range("B5:B25", "D5:D25").Address
```

then you will see that the address is `$B$5:$D$25` And hence it does that. If you do not want `C` to be included then replace

```
Range("B5:B25", "D5:D25")
```

with

```
Range("B5:B25,D5:D25")
```

[image]